# Logical / Physical processors supported

Tags: multi-core, cpu

Can anyone tell me the maximum number of **logical** as well as the maximum number of **physical** processors supported in the latest release of Ubuntu?

In the documentation online, I've found the 8 processor support for 32 bit, and 256 processors for 64 bit, but it is unclear whether it is referring to logical or physical processors.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Logical vs physical cores is a distinction made by the computer/CPU; the OS isn't really aware of any difference (if the OS wanted to get really picky about licensing, it could limit capability depending on what is going on in the CPU socket, but Linux doesn't).

If you're wondering about the maximum number of cores supported, you want to look to the logical cores, since each of those are a real CPU as far as the kernel is concerned.

Note: the 8-core limit in 32-bit is just a compiler option set on the generic kernel. The SMP kernel has support for more: https://superuser.com/a/172986/223699